# Counting functions and stirling numbers

Tags: combinatorics, functions, integer-partitions, stirling-numbers

Let S= { f | f: A $\rightarrow$ B, |Image(f)|=k}.

|A|=m, |B|=n.
where k $ \le n, k \le m $

|S|=$ {n \choose k} $ S(m,k) k!.

where S(m,k) are the striling numbers of the second kind.
What I can't understand is how does k! fit in ? Why do we have to multiply by k! ?

Also we know that the total number of functions from A $\rightarrow $ B is
$n^{m}$.

So is 
|S|=$n^{m}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom{n}k$ ways to pick a subset $I$ of $B$ of cardinality $k$ to be the image of a function $f\in S$. There are ${m\brace k}$, or in your notation $S(m,k)$, ways to partition $A$ into $k$ non-empty subsets. And there are then $k!$ ways to pair up these subsets with the $k$ members of $I$. That is, if the $k$ non-empty subsets of $S$ are $P_1,\ldots,P_k$, we can assign them in this order to any permutation of the $k$ members of $I$, and there are $k!$ such permutations. Thus, there are altogether

$$\binom{n}k{m\brace k}k!$$

such funtions. This is *not* $n^m$, as you can verify by calculating an example or two with small numbers; $n^m$ is the total number of functions from $A$ to $B$, so it includes those whose images have each possible size from $1$ through $n$. This means that

$$n^m=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}k{m\brace k}k!\;.$$

Comment: from what I understand if |Image(f)|=|B| then we are counting onto functions, if it is |A| we are counting one-to-one functions. So to calculate bijections do we just add the two ? @brian-m-scott

Comment: @lapin: No, that would give you the number of functions that are either one-to-one or onto; you want the ones that are both. If $k=m=|A|$, and $I$ is a subset of $B$ of cardinality $k$, a function from $A$ to $I$ is a bijection if and only if it’s one-to-one, so there are $\binom{n}m{m\brace m}m!=\binom{n}mm!$ bijections from $A$ to some subset of $B$.

Comment: I have no clue if this will be read since its been a while since the post was last active. However, why is the sum from $1$ through $n$ and not from $1$ through $m$?

What will change if the sum goes to $m$ and not $n$?

Comment: @cittee: The index $k$ ranges over the cardinalities of non-empty subsets of $B$, not subsets of $A$, and $|B|=n$, so its possible values are the integers $1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: The reason why Im asking is because Im trying to find a proof for the same sum-expression, but where the upper limit is $m$ instead of $n$. Or rather the exact expression $\sum_{k=1}^{m} S(m,k)P(n,k)=n^m$ but its the same since $\binom{n}{k}k!=P(n,k)$. Any ideas? Im absolutely following your reasoning but cannot seem to understand how to show it if the sum goes to $m$...

Comment: @cittee: Essentially the same argument works. If $f:A\to B$, and $|f[A]|=k$, then $f$ partitions $A$ into $k$ non-empty subsets. $A$ has only $m$ elements, so there can be at most $m$ of these subsets. Thus, we need only consider values of $k$ between $1$ and $m$ inclusive: it’s impossible to partition $A$ into more than $m$ subsets.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott hm yeah, I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: @cittee: You’re welcome!